# Seleccionar unicamente un checkbox (Español)

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, checkbox

quiero seleccionar un solo checkbox de mi formulario(que si al momento que seleccione el box_1 desmarque el box_2), lo hice con recyclerview y quiero obtener el texto que este trae

El código que tengo ahora debe seleccionar el que quiero y luego des seleccionar ese para seleccionar el otro

```
class AuthorizationFormAdapter(private val lista: List<Procedures>?) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AuthorizationFormAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var lastCheckedPosition: Int = 0
    lateinit var context: Context

    inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val checkBox: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_auth)


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_authform, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lista!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val procedure = lista?.get(position)
        holder.view.auth_name.text = procedure!!.name_procedure
        holder.view.cb_auth.isChecked = procedure.isChecked

        holder.view.cb_auth.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

            if (isChecked) {
                lista!![lastCheckedPosition].isChecked = false
                lastCheckedPosition = position
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Solo puedes seleccionar uno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            lista!![position].isChecked = isChecked
            notifyDataSetChanged() 
        }
}
```

Esta es mi clase Procedures, donde le tengo un boolean

```
class Procedures {
    var name_procedure: String? = ""
    var isChecked: Boolean = false

    constructor(name_procedure: String?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        this.name_procedure = name_procedure
        this.isChecked = isChecked
    }
}
```

Y mi Card XML es este:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/auth_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.../>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_auth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .... />
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar RadioButtons en vez de CheckBox están expresamente para la funcionalidad que deseas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtenerlo al hacer

```
val checkBoxChecked = list[adapter.lastCheckedPosition]
```

Cómo tienes la posición en la que está seleccionado, solo obtenlo del adaptador y úsalo como índice de la lista, y obtendrás el objeto. Después solo objeto le extraes la propia name.